# Evaluating $\int \frac{\operatorname dx}{x\log x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to integrate $\frac{1}{x\log x}$?

Could you give me some ideas on how to integrate this? thanks.

i've tried setting $u=(\log x)^{-1}$.

$\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dx} = x^{-1}$

But it didnt work...

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:**  For all $x>1$, $\dfrac 1{x\log (x)}=\dfrac{1/x}{\log (x)}$.

Comment: Thanks. It would be log(log x) :)

Comment: @user120495 Correct. **Edit:** actually not entirely correct as $\log(x)$ is not always positive.

Answer (score 6):

Hint. Use the substitution $u=\log(x)$.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll try it that way too

Answer (score 4):

Let : 
$$u = \log{x}$$
Then,
$$\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{1}{x}$$
$$du = \frac{1}{x}dx$$
Hence,
$$\begin{align}\int\frac{1}{x\log{x}}dx &=\int\frac{1}{\log{x}}\frac{1}{x}dx\\&= \int\frac{1}{u}du \\&= \log{|u|} + C \\&=\log|\log{u}| + C\end{align}$$